# Python errors on Linux - Version?

Tags: python, linux, class

I am running a python script which runs perfectly on OSX with python version 2.7.6. I am then running the same script on Linux with python version 2.6.5, and it is giving me the below errors, line numbers are not matching as I have cut down the script for an example. IS this a python version problem?

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Create_MD5.py", line 133, in <module>
    myApp = CreateMD5('myApp')
  File "Create_MD5.py", line 35, in __init__
    self.sendEmail()
  File "Create_MD5.py", line 124, in sendEmail
    server = smtplib.SMTP(self.host)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 239, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 295, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 273, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py", line 500, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Code example:

```
import hashlib
import threading
import os
import os.path
import sys
import time
import datetime
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

class CreateMD5(object):
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.host = "outlook"
        directory = "/RAIDS/RAID3"
        ..............


    def......

    def sendEmail(self):
        msg = MIMEMultipart()
        msg['From'] = self.fromaddr
        msg['To'] = self.toaddr
        msg['Subject'] = "Some Subject"
        body = "This is an example"
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
        server = smtplib.SMTP(self.host)
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(self.fromaddr, self.toaddr, text)

myApp = CreateMD5('myApp')
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but have you tried to put #!/usr/bin/python at the beginning of the file?

Comment: Added this and makes no difference. Still getting the errors.

Comment: what happens when you do: `ping outlook` on the Linux machine?

Comment: The last line of the error message is quite descriptive:socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: This is all about getaddrinfo and name resolution, which is more related to the operating system than to Python. Python just wraps the operating system libc's getaddrinfo function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is connection problem: `[EAI_AGAIN] The name could not be resolved at this time. Future attempts may succeed.`

You can check error codes for constants defined as `socket.EAI_*` and you see that -3 corresponds to `socket.EAI_AGAIN`. And the same tells you traceback, btw.

Comment: Sorted, commented out all the email stuff and the script runs. Although I have another issue.

Comment: feel free to ask __another__ question then (better to keep separate issues in seperate questions)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the following in python console and let us know what you see ?

```
 import smtplib                                                                                
 print smtplib.SMTP(self.host)
```